# SQL Server 2012 - Create a calculated column showing percentage in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a query for a report and capture what percentage of data has been filled in and display that as a calculated column.

So far I have wrote a query using joins to get me the required data:

Query:

```
SELECT
    SU.ID,
    MAX(SU.[GenderID]), 
    MAX(SU.[TelephoneNumber]), 
    MAX(SU.[MobileNumber]), 
    MAX(SU.[AddressID]), 
    MAX(SU.[WebSite]), 
    MAX(SU.[Narrative]), 
    MAX(SU.[IndividualTitleID]), 
    MAX(SU.[DateOfBirth]),


    MAX(SUED.SystemUserID) AS [SUEDID],
    MAX(SUE.ID) AS [SUEID],
    MAX(SUQ.ID) AS [SUQID],
    MAX(SUPB.ID) AS [SUPB],
    MAX(SUPQ.ID) AS [SUPQID],
    MAX(SUPI1.ID) AS [Skill],
    MAX(SUPI2.ID) AS [Achievement],
    MAX(SUPI3.ID) AS [Interest]
FROM 
    [Employed].[SystemUser] SU
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [Profile].[SystemUserEducation] SUED ON SU.ID = SUED.SystemUserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [Profile].[SystemUserQualification] SUQ ON SUED.ID = SUQ.SystemUserEducationID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [Profile].[SystemUserEmployment] SUE ON SU.ID = SUE.SystemUserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [Profile].[SystemUserProfessionalBody] SUPB ON SU.ID = SUPB.SystemUserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [Profile].[SystemUserProfessionalQualification] SUPQ ON SU.ID = SUPQ.SystemUserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [Profile].[SystemUserProfileItem] SUPI1 ON SU.ID = SUPI1.SystemUserID  AND SUPI1.SystemUserProfileItemTypeID = 1 -- Skills
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [Profile].[SystemUserProfileItem] SUPI2 ON SU.ID = SUPI2.SystemUserID  AND SUPI2.SystemUserProfileItemTypeID = 2 -- Achievement 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [Profile].[SystemUserProfileItem] SUPI3 ON SU.ID = SUPI3.SystemUserID  AND SUPI3.SystemUserProfileItemTypeID = 3 -- Interest
WHERE
    SU.ID = 4604
GROUP BY
    SU.ID
```

**Calculation**

There are 16 columns in the above query, I need to check if each column has data or not, if there is data then assign a 1 or if it's null then assign a 0.

Once I've got the sum total for columns which have data, I then want to perform a calculation like so - ***100 * Completed Columns / Total Columns*** I then want to display this as a column for that query.

Essentially this data will be used in a report.

Any advice on how I can do this in SQL would be great, Thanks

Comment: For your first check - you could use `CASE`- for example `CASE WHEN su.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS su_id_bool` - as for your calculation, are you asking how to do the calculation or do you already know?

Comment: which rdbms? Oracle, mysql? sql-server, if so version 2012+?  Also encourage you to put in some sample data and desired result based on that data it helps people to visualize the solution.  Please include as DML statements. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056

Comment: doublesidedstickytape - thanks am not sure how I would do that calculation

Comment: Matt - Noted, will update where I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select
SU.ID,
SU.[GenderID],
SU.[TelephoneNumber], 
SU.[MobileNumber], 
SU.[AddressID], 
SU.[WebSite],
SU.[Narrative], 
SU.[IndividualTitleID], 
SU.[DateOfBirth],


MAX(SUED.SystemUserID) AS [SUEDID],
MAX(SUE.ID) AS [SUEID],
MAX(SUQ.ID) AS [SUQID],
MAX(SUPB.ID) AS [SUPB],
MAX(SUPQ.ID) AS [SUPQID],
MAX(SUPI1.ID) AS [Skill],
MAX(SUPI2.ID) AS [Achievement],
MAX(SUPI3.ID) AS [Interest],

100 * (
    CASE WHEN MAX(SUED.SystemUserID) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    + CASE WHEN MAX(SUE.ID) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    + CASE WHEN MAX(SUQ.ID) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    + CASE WHEN MAX(SUPB.ID) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    + CASE WHEN MAX(SUPQ.ID) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    + CASE WHEN MAX(SUPI1.ID) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    + CASE WHEN MAX(SUPI2.ID) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    + CASE WHEN MAX(SUPI3.ID) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
) / 8.0

FROM [Employed].[SystemUser] SU
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Profile].[SystemUserEducation] SUED ON SU.ID = SUED.SystemUserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Profile].[SystemUserQualification] SUQ ON SUED.ID = SUQ.SystemUserEducationID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Profile].[SystemUserEmployment] SUE ON SU.ID = SUE.SystemUserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Profile].[SystemUserProfessionalBody] SUPB ON SU.ID = SUPB.SystemUserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Profile].[SystemUserProfessionalQualification] SUPQ ON SU.ID = SUPQ.SystemUserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Profile].[SystemUserProfileItem] SUPI1 ON SU.ID = SUPI1.SystemUserID  AND SUPI1.SystemUserProfileItemTypeID = 1 -- Skills
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Profile].[SystemUserProfileItem] SUPI2 ON SU.ID = SUPI2.SystemUserID  AND SUPI2.SystemUserProfileItemTypeID = 2 -- Achievement 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Profile].[SystemUserProfileItem] SUPI3 ON SU.ID = SUPI3.SystemUserID  AND SUPI3.SystemUserProfileItemTypeID = 3 -- Interest

Where SU.ID = 4604
Group by
    SU.ID,
    SU.[GenderID],
    SU.[TelephoneNumber], 
    SU.[MobileNumber], 
    SU.[AddressID], 
    SU.[WebSite],
    SU.[Narrative], 
    SU.[IndividualTitleID], 
    SU.[DateOfBirth],
```